# Escape characters while searching

Tags: r

If I write and then read a text file in R

```
full_name <- '"Margie" Smith'
write(full_name, "m.txt")
tt <- readLines("m.txt")
```

the result tt shows that m.txt is escaped.

How can I search for '"Margie" Smith' in m.txt?

Comment: I don't know, what you really want to see in output.txt? "Margie" Smith? Yes?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to see.

Comment: I have right output ("Margie" Smith) in output.txt? Which one do you have?

Comment: `grepl( '"Margie" Smith', tt)`  returns `True`, so search seems successful. If you don't want to see escape characters, you could use `cat(tt)`

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what you see now and what your expected output would be? It might also be helpful to describe your use case. What problem do you try to solve and what fails currently. Answers are much more likely with such an edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could use `grep`to find "Margie" Smith in the txt file, and `cat` to remove escape characters:

```
full_name <- c('"Margie" Smith','"John" Smith')
write(full_name, "m.txt")
tt <- readLines("m.txt")

GetMargie <- grep('"Margie" Smith', readLines("m.txt"), value = TRUE)

cat(GetMargie)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always use `\` before [special characters](http://mathcenter.oxford.emory.edu/site/math117/stringsInR/).
For example:

```
grepl(pattern =  "\"Margie\" Smith", x = tt)
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following solution.

1. For writing and reading, use the `fwrite` and `fread` functions from the `data.table` package. These are the fastest functions for reading and writing text files.
2. Change the quotes from `'"Margie" Smith'` to `"'Margie' Smith"`

```
library(data.table)
full_name = data.frame(l = "'Margie' Smith")
fwrite(full_name, "m1.txt")
tt = fread(text = "m1.txt", sep = NULL)
tt$l
```

output

```
[1] "'Margie' Smith"
```

This will also help your solution

```
full_name <- "'Margie' Smith"
write(full_name, "m.txt")
tt <- readLines("m.txt")
tt
```

output

```
[1] "'Margie' Smith"
```

However, remember that reading and writing are a bit slower in this case. So if you have large amounts of large files this could make a difference.

The whole problem arises because a character type variable in R is always enclosed in double quotes. Consider the code below.

```
s1 = "a"
#[1] "a"

s2 = 'a'
#[1] "a"

s3 = "'a'"
#[1] "'a'"

s4 = '"a"'
#[1] "\"a\""
```

As you can see, single quotes at the beginning and end of a string are converted to double. And if you want to have double quotes in the text, it will be changed to `\"`.

### Update

Then read it this way

```
full_name <- "'Margie' Smith"
write(full_name, "m.txt")
tt = gsub("\"", "'", readLines("m.txt"))
tt
```

output

```
[1] "'Margie' Smith"
```

Comment: This makes sense except I cannot actually create the m.txt file.  It is created by a download from an http://.  The double quotes are already in the file.

Comment: See my answer update. This should solve your problem definitively

Answer (score 0):

Most characters can be used in a string, with a couple of exceptions, one being the backslash character, " \ ". This character is called the escape character and is used to insert characters that would otherwise be difficult to add. Sorry if this is too general!

Comment: This may help you or may not, but just for reference!

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(111)

#for searching a vector of strings
(random_data <- 
map(1:10, ~sample(letters, 5) %>%
      reduce(str_c)) %>%
  unlist())
#>  [1] "ntsoe" "chqmj" "dohnp" "qguoa" "ihcgt" "dftzy" "euzfd" "ijrwu" "majpx"
#> [10] "gdtqv"

full_name <- c(random_data, '"Margie" Smith')
write(full_name, "m.txt")
tt <- readLines("m.txt")

##REVELVANT CODE###
tt %>%
  str_subset('\"Margie\" Smith')
#> [1] "\"Margie\" Smith"
##REVELVANT CODE###



#for searching an individual string
(random_data1 <- 
  map(1:10, ~sample(letters, 5) %>%
        reduce(str_c)) %>%
  reduce(str_c) %>% 
  {paste(., '"Margie" Smith')})
#> [1] "oxpmsoxajrusaklfglzrilrfmtzefvfgqjdxwcmersfhdldzvb \"Margie\" Smith"

##REVELVANT CODE###
str_detect(random_data1, '\"Margie\" Smith')
#> [1] TRUE
##REVELVANT CODE###
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>